# Help setting up hardware RAID10 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, raid

We are trying to setup a RAID10 on an Ubuntu workstation. We acquired 4X16T Seagate NAS HDDs and set this up on an Asus PRIME Z690-P D4 motherboard. This motherboard has the following RAID controller:

```
sudo lspci -knn | grep 'RAID bus controller'
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller [8086:467f]
```

In the Bios, we properly set up the 4 HDDs as a RAID10 array.

After booting into Ubuntu, we are still seeing the 4 individual HDDs:

```
sudo lsblk -e7 -o +FSTYPE
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS                            FSTYPE
sda                         8:0    0  14.6T  0 disk                                        isw_raid_member
sdb                         8:16   0  14.6T  0 disk                                        isw_raid_member
sdc                         8:32   0  14.6T  0 disk                                        isw_raid_member
sdd                         8:48   0  14.6T  0 disk                                        isw_raid_member
nvme1n1                   259:0    0   3.6T  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1               259:1    0   3.6T  0 part /mnt/hive                              ext4
nvme0n1                   259:2    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:3    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi                              vfat
├─nvme0n1p2               259:4    0     2G  0 part /boot                                  ext4
└─nvme0n1p3               259:5    0 950.8G  0 part                                        LVM2_member
  ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm                                         ext4
  └─ubuntu--vg-lv--0      253:1    0 850.8G  0 lvm  /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell ext4
```

It seems that the HDDs are indeed recognised as part of a RAID 10 array:

```
sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 68bc013b
         Family : 68bc013b
     Generation : 00000003
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : f751162b:c3b8e1fa:1c9877d8:4c9ce4b0
       Checksum : d50a3a2a correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 4
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : ZL28KR52
          State : active
             Id : 00000000
    Usable Size : 31251753984 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)

[Volume1]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : 826834df:4fad6488:a86c8db7:7e8d3558
     RAID Level : 10
        Members : 4
          Slots : [UUUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 62503507968 (29.11 TiB 32.00 TB)
   Per Dev Size : 31251754248 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 122077164
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : uninitialized
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 1

  Disk01 Serial : ZL25BAWR
          State : active
             Id : 00000001
    Usable Size : 31251753984 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)

  Disk02 Serial : ZL247HYM
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 31251753984 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)

  Disk03 Serial : ZL270G5R
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 31251753984 (14.55 TiB 16.00 TB)
```

But for some reason, we can't see a volume corresponding to the RAID 10 array.

I've been looking for solutions, but couldn't really find a solution for my particular issue. Can we actually set up a RAID 10 array in Bios, and have it recognised as single volume in Ubuntu? Do we need to install some drivers for Ubuntu to be able to recognise them?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!